# Does my catch phrase make sense?

Tags: grammaticality, translation

I recently added a short catch phrase to my SE [profile](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/28142/user2016436?tab=profile) which goes like this:

> Start out your fastest, and slowly but surely, go faster

### Question Summary:

1. Is this sentence grammatically correct?
2. Is the meaning of this sentence clear?

### Background

In the Israeli cult movie, [Operation Grandma](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/operation_grandma), there is an [epic scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wrf48uH9VMQ) where one of the main characters, who is a praised swimmer in his Kibbutz, is asked for tips on how one can improve his swimming skills, in the context of a swimming race. As an answer he says:

> אתה מתחיל הכי מהר שלך, ולאט לאט אתה מגביר

This is the sentence I'm trying to translate. Basically, this is a ridiculous answer that means: For one to improve his swimming results, he must start swimming as fast as he can, and then swim faster.

I was wondering whether or not my translation is grammatically correct, but also if it captures the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation is understandable and grammatically correct.

> Start out your fastest then, slowly but surely, go faster.

The meaning you seem to want to catch is

> Start as **fast as you can**... then **go faster**

the colloquialism might be

> Start **fastest**, then go **faster**

meaning that in the beginning, one does as **best as one's ability will allow** (fastest), and then **exceed it** (go faster).  It sounds like something a coach would say **to exhort** his players, along the lines of

> I don't mind if my players give **110%** - *Jose Morinho*

There is possibly a slight difference in the meaning and feeling with the Hebrew, since the Hebrew says **gradual improvement** instead of an **immediate improvement**, i.e. during a competition where athletes might achieve a **personal best**

The basic meaning is to **do one's best from the start**, and then **improve upon it**.

Comment: Nicely summarized and paraphrased. I'd add one footnote: If the O.P. wanted to capture the essence of "slowly but surely," that could be done by adding one word: _Start as fast as you can... then **gradually** go faster_.

Answer (score -1):

To answer you question

1. No
2. No

What you can say is:

> start fast, end faster